# Use Image in SwiftUI with either URL or Data without UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have downloaded an image in bytes (`Data`). I stored it with FileManager in the cache of the user's device. I was wondering if I could create an `Image` with either `Data` or a local `URL`, I am currently using `UIImage` but I want to support macOS.

Is there a full SwiftUI way of creating an `Image` with `URL` or `Data` without UIKit/UIImage?

Comment: Look up AsyncImage it’s new

Answer (score 0):

if your question is about showing and image in macos, that you already have downloaded (and is in the `cachesDirectory`), then try something like this, to create an image from your image in bytes: (using NSImage for macos)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var img = NSImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(nsImage: img)
            .onAppear {
                do {
                    // local file
                    let url = try FileManager.default
                        .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                        .appendingPathComponent("kat")  // <--- your file name here
                        .appendingPathExtension("png")
                    
                    print("----> url: \(url)")
                    
                    // even from the net
//                    let url = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Red-billed_gull%2C_Red_Zone%2C_Christchurch%2C_New_Zealand.jpg")!
                    
                    if let nsimg = NSImage(contentsOf: url) { img = nsimg }
                } catch {
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }
    }
    
}
```